# Safari web browser will NOT perform Asynchronous Automatic Refresh. Rather it will do a full page reload

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin, ajax

I have added an announcement web App, to SP2013 my team site, and for the App part Ajax option I enabled the following:-

- Enable Asynchronous Update
- Show Manual Refresh Button
- Enable Asynchronous Automatic Refresh
- Automatic Refreshing Interval (seconds) = 60.

But on Safari after 60 seconds or when the user manually clicks on the “Refresh” button,  the current web page will do a full reload and not an asynchronous reload. While on IE, FireFox and Chrome they will do asynchronous reload. can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 1):

On Technet you can find the [Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx)

The first paragraph says:
SharePoint 2013 supports several commonly used web browsers, such as Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Apple Safari. **However, certain web browsers could cause some SharePoint 2013 functionality to be downgraded, limited, or available only through alternative steps.**